# What is this arthropod? (found in Lapland - Finland)

Tags: zoology, entomology, arthropod

I found this arthropod climbing the wall of my room in Lapland, Finland.
[image]

(the max width is about 0.5 cm)

What is it? Is it dangerous?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The picture is not great but I'd assume a [pseudoscorpion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudoscorpion) of some sort. Here is one common species found where humans live but I can't be sure about Lapland specifically and doubt ID is possible at the species level from your image: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chelifer_cancroides

If so, I'm not aware of any harm from these directly, but they can be predators of insects that eat rotting wood, which in turn may indicate a problem with moisture in your structure. A single sighting is not something I would worry about unless you have other signs from those sorts of prey themselves.

Comment: thank you the image in the wikipedia link you shared matches

Comment: According to [this observations map](https://laji.fi/en/taxon/MX.70200), pseudoscorpions do live in Lapland, as does [_C. cancroides_](https://laji.fi/en/taxon/MX.201753) specifically.